# Zpub vs xpub not matching between seedsigner and sparrow?

Tags: multi-signature, xpub, sparrow-wallet, seedsigner

Generated a multisig xpub via Seedsigner. Loaded this to sparrow via camera-reading of seedsigner's QR code. Sparrow & Seedsigner fingerprints match, as do derivation paths, but Seedsigner displays Xpub as: ZpubXYZ while Sparrow displays Xpub as: XpubABC. Why is this? My cursory understanding is just that these are different formats of the same thing, but how can I verify that Sparrow has correctly imported this information if the displayed Xpub's don't match? Just verifying the fingerprint match is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a different format. Sparrow can toggle between zpub and xpub configuration (as a display) and you can thus verify the xpub in this way as well.